# Regex issue in fitnesse

Tags: regex, fitnesse

I am having trouble using regex in fitnesse. I want to get a regex for a sequence of 10 digits. I tried the following-

```
=~/\d{10}/
```

and

```
=~/[0-9]{10}/
```

But these are not working. For a sample input say "1234", the above regex is passing as green.

What would be the regex to test a sequence of 10 digits in fitnesse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding start/end anchors, e.g.

```
=~/^\d{10}$/
```

or perhaps word anchors if the 10 digit number is embedded in other text:

```
=~/\b\d{10}\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

your regex match sequence of only 10 digits, but not 4
you must write `\d{1,10}`

Comment: but {1,10} would match at least 1 & at most 10? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: A 10 digits sequence is required, while an unexpected match occurs with 4 digits sequence.